Selenium.py not finding element content
I'm using selenium.py in a discord bot, and whenever i run this function:
# bot.py
class Bot():
    async def find_player(self, name): # if the Bot is in a game
        _class = 'fgui-lb-entry-n'
        names = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, _class)))
        print("Player names found:", [name.text for name in names])
        
        for _name in names:
            print(_name.text)
            if _name.text == name:
                return True
        return False

# main.py
BOT = Bot()
for _ in range(60):
    if BOT.find_player("name"):
        # do something if true
    asyncio.sleep(1)
# after 60 seconds, do something

it always prints [''] if there is 1 player in the game, or ['', ''] if there are two players in the game.
I have tried switching to XPATH, I have confirmed several times that the class name is correct.
The output should be ['TradeBot', 'name'] (TradeBot is the name of the bot in the game)
HTML
<div class="fgui-lb-entry fgui-lb-entry-self" style="height: 30px; top: 0px;">
    <span class="fgui-lb-entry-i">1.</span>
    <span class="fgui-lb-entry-cl">[MRSC]</span>
    <span class="fgui-lb-entry-n">JesterIsHere</span>
</div>

Edit: website is bandit.rip
Click the create/join lobby and create a lobby
The element will be in the leaderboard

Are you sure .text is the right attribute?  Can you show us some examples of the html elements?

Sure, here is the lineage of the element
<div class="fgui-lb" style="height: 30px;">
    <div class="fgui-lb-entry fgui-lb-entry-self" style="height: 30px; top: 0px;"> 
         <span class="fgui-lb-entry-i">1.</span>
         <span class="fgui-lb-entry-cl">[MRSC]</span>
         <span class="fgui-lb-entry-n">JesterIsHere</span>
    </div>
</div>

From what I have seen, .text is the right attribute, but I am obviously not confident enough to say it is 100% the right attribute

Edit the HTML into your question and properly format it using a beautifier... there are many online.

The problem with EC.presence_of_all_elements_located() is that it doesn't know how many of the elements there are supposed to be. If it finds at least one, it moves on. Rather than grabbing all matching elements and then looping through them all to check to see if the contained text is equal to the name you are looking for, you can instead just use an XPath and find the element that contains the desired name. If it's found, return True. If it times out and throws a TimeoutException, then return False.
I would rewrite it like this
# bot.py
class Bot():
    async def find_player(self, name): # if the Bot is in a game
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//span[@class='fgui-lb-entry-n'][text()='{name}']")))
            return True
        except (TimeoutException):
            return False

